# SQLite SELECT with Limit performance

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have an android app that performs a SELECT * statement over a DB with ~5M records. The query takes about 1 minute to complete and I was wondering whether it can be speed up by using indexes or something else.

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE] where timestamp > [TIMESTAMP] ORDER by timestamp ASC LIMIT 0,500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the lookup and the sorting in this query can be sped up with an index on the `timestamp` column:

```
CREATE INDEX table_timestamp_index ON [TABLE](timestamp);
```